# make error as unable to find cblas

Tags: python

I am trying to run the [BdG-TMAT code](http://software-lisc.fbk.eu/bdg/). The folder here has both Fortran and python files since the main run file BDG_K.py uses some fortran functions. So to run the fortran code, I use a converter f2py which converts tmatf.f90 to tmatf.so. (f2py comes auto-installed with numpy). I am running make of the BdG-Tmat folder where I get the error as follows:

```
gfortran:f77: /tmp/tmpQErUyR/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/potsub-f2pywrappers.f
/usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -Wall -shared /tmp/tmpQErUyR/tmp/tmpQErUyR/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/potsubmodule.o /tmp/tmpQErUyR/tmp/tmpQErUyR/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.o /tmp/tmpQErUyR/potsub.o /tmp/tmpQErUyR/tmp/tmpQErUyR/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/potsub-f2pywrappers.o potsubi.o -lgsl -llapack -lcblas -lgslcblas -lgfortran -o ./potsub.so
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lcblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lcblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Command "/usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -Wall -shared /tmp/tmpQErUyR/tmp/tmpQErUyR/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/potsubmodule.o /tmp/tmpQErUyR/tmp/tmpQErUyR/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.o /tmp/tmpQErUyR/potsub.o /tmp/tmpQErUyR/tmp/tmpQErUyR/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/potsub-f2pywrappers.o potsubi.o -lgsl -llapack -lcblas -lgslcblas -lgfortran -o ./potsub.so" failed with exit status 1
make: *** [potsub.so] Error 1
```

Thus on running the python file in this folder, I am getting the following error :

```
     $python BDG_K.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BDG_K.py", line 29, in <module>
    import tmatf
ImportError: /home/arpit/Desktop/BdG-Tmat/tmatf.so: undefined symbol: dsbevx_
```

this mentioned symbol is not there in the original file (where it is dsbevx instead of dsbevx_)

Please guide how to install CBLAS correctly in order to remove the first error and whether the second error is related to the first. I tried making the CBLAS source folder but it does not work fine. I followed this :http://vibrationdata.wordpress.com/2011/11/07/install-cblas-in-ubuntu/ .

Comment: Do you have lapack installed? If not see [this forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1505249) If that helps come back and we will track down the package with the missing symbols

Comment: Yes, I have lapack installed. As I see after the 'make' of BdG-Tmat, it is able to locate llapack, lgsl, lblas etc.. but it is unable to locate only lcblas. Thanks.

Comment: it looks as if you may need 1 more library. Does [this link](http://www.seehuhn.de/pages/linear#installation) help?

Comment: @ECarterYoung : The program is working fine. Thanks a lot :-) . If you write it as answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for these errors to disappear you need to install lapack and atlas.  I found directions at the following site on [Numerical Linear Algebra](http://www.seehuhn.de/pages/linear#installation).  You can either use synaptic or `apt-get` to install the packages listed on that page, and your transformation library will compile.